# Python Graph API Send Email No suitable token exists in cache and Access Denied

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using below code to send email using microsoft graph api credentials getting below mentioned errors , from postman email is being sent successfully.
Not sure what is missing.

```
import json
import msal
import requests

client_id = '6c762**************'
client_secret = 'F-S**************************'
tenant_id = 'e*****************************'
authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_credential=client_secret,
    authority=authority)

scopes = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]

result = None
result = app.acquire_token_silent(scopes, account=None)

if not result:
    print(
        "No suitable token exists in cache. Let's get a new one from Azure Active Directory.")
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scopes)

# if "access_token" in result:
#     print("Access token is " + result["access_token"])


if "access_token" in result:
    userId = "support@****.com"
    endpoint = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/sendMail'
    toUserEmail = "hi****@gmail.com"

    email_msg = {'Message': {'Subject': "Test Sending Email from Python",
                             'Body': {'ContentType': 'Text', 'Content': "This is a test email."},
                             'ToRecipients': [{'EmailAddress': {'Address': toUserEmail}}]
                             },
                 'SaveToSentItems': 'true'}
    r = requests.post(endpoint,
                      headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']}, json=email_msg)
    if r.ok:
        print('Sent email successfully')
    else:
        print(r.json())
else:
    print(result.get("error"))
    print(result.get("error_description"))
    print(result.get("correlation_id"))
```

Below Are Error Detail :-

No suitable token exists in cache. Let's get a new one from Azure Active Directory.
{'error': {'code': 'ErrorAccessDenied', 'message': 'Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.'}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, I too got **same error** when I ran your code in my environment by granting `Mail.Send` permission of **Delegated** type:

[image]

To resolve the error, make sure to grant <kbd>**Mail.Send**</kbd> permission of **Application** type as you are using client credentials flow that generates app-only token.

[image]

When I ran the same code again after granting permission of **Application** type, I got the **response** like this:

```cs
import json
import msal
import requests

client_id = 'appID'
client_secret = 'secret'
tenant_id = 'tenantId'
authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_credential=client_secret,
    authority=authority)

scopes = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]

result = None
result = app.acquire_token_silent(scopes, account=None)

if not result:
    print(
        "No suitable token exists in cache. Let's get a new one from Azure Active Directory.")
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scopes)

# if "access_token" in result:
#     print("Access token is " + result["access_token"])


if "access_token" in result:
    userId = "xxxxx_rk@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
    endpoint = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/sendMail'
    toUserEmail = "sridevi.xxxxxxxx@gmail.com"

    email_msg = {'Message': {'Subject': "Test Sending Email from Python",
                             'Body': {'ContentType': 'Text', 'Content': "This is a test email."},
                             'ToRecipients': [{'EmailAddress': {'Address': toUserEmail}}]
                             },
                 'SaveToSentItems': 'true'}
    r = requests.post(endpoint,
                      headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']}, json=email_msg)
    if r.ok:
        print('Sent email successfully')
    else:
        print(r.json())
else:
    print(result.get("error"))
    print(result.get("error_description"))
    print(result.get("correlation_id"))
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in `Sent Items` of users where email sent successfully as below:

[image]